# I can't navigate without the navigation prop of react-navigation with react-i18next container

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-i18next

I apply the *navigation example without the navigation prop* of the react-navigations docs (**NavigationService**), but I can't make it work with *react-i18next*.

I applied the example of the documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html in my code:

```
// App.js

import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/lib/integration/react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { I18nextProvider, withNamespaces } from 'react-i18next';
import { persistor, store } from './src/store';
import I18n from './src/localization';
import Navigation from './src/navigation';
import NavigationService from './src/navigation/NavigationService';
import Loader from './src/screens/components/Loader';

class NavigationStack extends React.Component {
  static router = Navigation.router;
  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;
    return <Navigation screenProps={{ t, I18n }} {...this.props} />;
  }
};

const ReloadNavOnLanguageChange = withNamespaces(['common', 'server'], {
  bindI18n: 'languageChanged',
  bindStore: false,
})(createAppContainer(NavigationStack));


export default class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={<Loader />} persistor={persistor}>
          <I18nextProvider i18n={ I18n } >
            <ReloadNavOnLanguageChange ref={navigatorRef => {
              NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
            }} />
          </I18nextProvider>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  };
};


// Navigation.js

...
export default Navigation = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    Login: LoginScreen,
    App: AppScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
  }
);


// NavigationService.js

Apply the same code that's in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html


// Any JS module of my project (actions, helpers, components, etc.)

import NavigationService from 'path-to-NavigationService.js';
...
NavigationService.navigate('Login');
```

When the authorization token is validated and the result is negative, the login screen must be opened (`NavigationService.navigate('Login')`) but it returns the error `_navigator.dispatch is not a function` in NavigationService.js:

```
const navigate = (routeName, params) => {
   // DISPATCH ERROR
   _navigator.dispatch(
     NavigationActions.navigate({
       routeName,
       params
     })
   );
};
```

Dependencies:

- react 16.5.0
- react-native 57.1
- react-i18next 9.0.0
- react-navigation 3.1.2

Any suggestion? Has anyone else found this scenario?

Comment: It is great that you have found the solution to your problem so it is recommended that you post an answer instead of adding [SOLVED] or similar. please read [ask] and [answer]

Comment: ... sorry, wrong edit ...

Answer (score 0):

Using the `innerRef` option of the `withNamespaces` hoc of react-i18next instead of passing the function through the `ref` property of the root component… AS THE DOCUMENTATION OF REACT-I18NETX SAYS!

```
// App.js

...
const ReloadNavOnLanguageChange = withNamespaces(['common', 'server'], {
  bindI18n: 'languageChanged',
  bindStore: false,
  innerRef: (ref) => NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(ref)
})(createAppContainer(NavigationStack));

export default class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <ReloadNavOnLanguageChange />
      ...
    );
  };
}
```